# How to convert a string into JSX in React 17

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Given some string:

```
const someString = "<p>Here is some string <strong>with some nested HTML</strong></p>"
```

I could remove the `<p>` and `</p>` from the string and then with React do:

```
React.createElement('p', {
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML: {
    __html: html,
  },
})
```

(We are assuming `html` here is the string `someString` with the removed `p` tags)

However, React 17 released with the new JSX Transform: https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html

Meaning React no longer compiles down to `React.createElement` an instead directly compiles down to JSX.

Is there a way to accomplish this with the new JSX Transform?

Comment: *"instead directly compiles down to JSX"* - I'm not sure what you mean by that, the transform still outputs plain JS, just changing `React.createElement('h1', null, 'Hello world')` to `_jsx('h1', { children: 'Hello world' })` and auto-injecting the new import rather than requiring the developer to ensure `React` is in scope.

Comment: You are right!! you can convert `React.createElement` to `_jsx` while importing `import { jsx as _jsx } from 'react/jsx-runtime';`

I just had to use `// @ts-ignore` to ignore the import from `react/jsx-runtime`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact yes you can using `JSX` syntax similar to `React.createElement`

```
React.createElement('p', {
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML: {
    __html: html,
  },
})
```

will become

```
_jsx('p', {
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML: {
    __html: html,
  },
})
```

You will however need to import:
`import { jsx as _jsx } from 'react/jsx-runtime';`

Note: My issues was Typescript was complaingin `Could not find a declaration file for module 'react/jsx-runtime'.` I needed to add `// @ts-ignore` to ignore the JSX import